# Changing the source of a Sharepoint List View

Tags: sharepoint, listview, web-parts

Effectively I am looking to change the viewed Document Library within an exsisting List View Web Part from 'Document Library #1' to Document Library #2'. I want to do so without having to re-create the entire web part (e.g. settings & views) as I would have to do this multiple times.

Sharepoint version is 2007 and Sharepoint Designer is not avaliable.

**Context:** I am currently building a Sharepoint area which will consist of multiple ASPX pages all based off an original layout. This layout includes a List View web part that directly views a Document Library.

Each ASPX page has a Document Library attributed to it (e.g. Page1.aspx and DocLib1), which I wish to display within this List View web part.

Page1.aspx was setup just fine (effectively the original). When setting up Page2.aspx as a direct copy of the first, I am unable to change the List View from DocLib1 to DocLib2 as there seems no option to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The list view web part isn't easily customizable unless you can edit the xml for the web part and change some guids. If you want to be able to change the source list through the browser you will need to use a different web part - the content query web part is an out of box option, though obviously that is quite different from the standard list view.

You may also be able to do something with with list templates - if you can use a custom template instead of the standard document library template, you may be able to alter AllItems.aspx to do what you need.